# How to make "sending" word when my mail is being sent and replace it with "Mail sent" when page stop loading or mail is sent

Tags: php, email

I used php mailer to sent mail i want the browser to show something like "Sending" when the mail is being sent or the browser is sending the mail and show "Message sent" when it had sent the mail .How do i achieve it? which language is use javascript or php or something else.
Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With ajax you can do that. I use jquery:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Before the $.ajax and after the `$(".button").click(function() {` you can add your message and block your button and form from re-submitting while is still submitting the form.

This tutorial is a little bit old but you can learn from it. I prefer use `$('#formId').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();` instead `$(".button").click(function() {`, with the submit you can track not just the click on button but the submit when hitting `enter` from keyboard.

Comment: The link you gave me is helpful but it looks like i have to start coding in jquery from the begining and i have already made my php script of sending email with phpmailer,is there any way to do little modification and get the desire effect instead of purely coding with  jquery or ajax from the very begining .

Comment: Try that https://gist.github.com/lslucas/858d43a0d3de1b1986b9
your contact form php need to return the string true if the email has been sent successfully